# How to commit date in "git log --all --graph --oneline --simplify-by-decoration"

Tags: git, git-log

I use `git log --all --graph --oneline --simplify-by-decoration` to show large git commit history, but there is no commit date, what can add date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following seems to be the closest to what you need based on your color needs, it adds commit date per your format, check it out to see if it helps:

```
git log --all --graph --oneline --simplify-by-decoration --date=short --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h%Creset%C(red)%C(bold)%d%Creset%C(white)(%cd)%Creset %s"
```

For further reading and to choose from a myriad number of options check the Pretty Format docs as listed by @tymtam on the other answer above :[Pretty Format docs](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats)

Comment: May I set `HEAD ->` to cyan, local branch name to green and remote branch to red?

Comment: @mikezang try this: ```git log --all --graph --oneline --simplify-by-decoration --date=short --pretty=format:"%h%C(auto)%d%C(reset) %s (%an, %ar)%d%Creset%C(white)(%cd)%Creset %s"
```

Comment: So, the above should give you the default colors for Head, local and remote branch and also has the date in your desired format(YYYY-MM-DD), inorder to play around with colors further check the docs out.

Comment: Here is what I need `git log --graph --all --oneline --simplify-by-decoration --date=format:%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M:%S --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h%C(auto)%d% %C(white) %cd%Creset %s"`. Thank you very much! You gave me the hints:)

Comment: Sounds awesome 

Answer (score 1):

You can try `--pretty='%h %an %aD %s'`

See [Pretty Formats](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats)

---

Update for 'I want to keep the original color and date in YYYY-MM-DD format...'

`git log your_other_options --pretty='%Cgreen%h%Creset %Cblue%
cd%Creset %smont' --date=short`

Comment: I tried but not get the same result, can you help me?

Comment: "Pretty Formats" not "Pettty Formats". (SO won't let me edit <6 characters, perhaps the author can edit?)